# Python update Database during multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing to perform jobs parallel, my Goal is to use multi cpu core and hence i choosen multiprocessing module instead of threading module

Now i have method, which uses subprocess module to execute linux shell command, i need to filter it and update the results to DB.

For every thread, subprocess execution time may differ some threads input execution time may be 10 seconds for other it may be 15 seconds.

My concern is will always get same thread execution result or different thread execution result,

or i have to go for locking mechanism, if yes can you provide me example that suitable for my requirement

Below is the example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
from subprocess import check_output
import multiprocessing


class Test:

    # Convert bytes to UTF-8 string
    @staticmethod
    def bytes_to_string(string_convert):
        if not isinstance(string_convert, bytes) and isinstance(string_convert, str):
            return string_convert, True
        elif isinstance(string_convert, bytes):
            string_convert = string_convert.decode("utf-8")
        else:
            print("Passed in non-byte type to convert to string: {0}".format(string_convert))
            return "", False

        return string_convert, True

    # Execute commands in Linux shell
    @staticmethod
    def command_output(command):
        try:
            output = check_output(command)
        except Exception as e:
            return e, False

        output, state = Test.bytes_to_string(output)

        return output, True

    @staticmethod
    def run_multi(num):

        test_result, success = Test.command_output(["curl", "-sb", "-H", "Accept: application/json", "http://127.0.0.1:5500/stores"])
        out = json.loads(test_result)
        #Update Database is safer here or i need to use any locks




if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Test()
    input_list = list(range(0, 1000))
    numberOfThreads = 100
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(numberOfThreads)

    p.map(test.run_multi, input_list)
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what sort of updates you're doing in the database...

If it's a full database, it'll have its own locking mechanisms; you'll need to work with them, but other than that it's already designed to handle concurrent access.

For example, if the update involves inserting a row, you can just do that; the database will end up with all the rows, each exactly once.

Comment: I have to insert rows, my code is good enough to handle correct?

Comment: Yeah, should be fine. Would have to see the row-inserting code...